# Comparing 2 vectors using relational operators

Tags: c++, vector, relational-operators

I tried comparing 2 vectors using relational operators.

```
vector<int>v1 {1, 2, 3};
vector<int>v2 {3, 40, 4};

cout<<(v1<v2)<<endl;    // Prints 1
cout<<(v1>v2)<<endl;    // Prints 0
```

What I am not sure of is on what basis is the comparison happening? It seems that it is comparing element by element. But I can't find any resource regarding that. Any help regarding a resource or an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: _It seems that it is comparing element by element. But I can't find any resource regarding that._ FYI: [operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=,<=>(std::vector)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp). You can find more with [google "std::vector less"](https://www.google.com/search?q=std%3A%3Avector+less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What I am not sure of is on what basis is the comparison happening?*

The C++ reference says:

> ```
> template< class T, class Alloc >
> bool operator<( const std::vector<T,Alloc>& lhs,
>                 const std::vector<T,Alloc>& rhs );
> ```
>
> Compares the contents of `lhs` and `rhs` lexicographically.

Lexicographic order could be roughly said as ordering the contents in alphabetic order.

Thus, when you compare `v1 > v2`, it'll return true once the contents in it of the `lhs` are lexicographically greater than the contents of `rhs`.

**Exception:** However, if both vectors are equal, then the comparison will return false:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v2{1, 2, 3};
std::cout << (v1 > v2) + ' ' + (v1 < v2) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

bool operator<(const std::vector& rhs) lexicographically compares the contents, return `true` if lhs are less than rhs, and false otherwise.